# Coldfusion automatically adds full path to links starting with #

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm working on creating HTML snapshots for an AJAX application that is to use Google AJAX crawling. I'm accessing this page through a cfhttp request. The reason for this is that this app is going to be embedded on sites and those sites use lots of different server-side languages and rewritting it in every language is not practical.

When I create an anchor link, like so,

```
<a class='icf_btn_small' href='##!year=#YearID#'>#YearID#</a>
```

Coldfusion outputs to the server a full url, like so:

```
<a class='icf_btn_small' href='http://example.com:80/snapshots/#!year=2016'>2016</a>
```

Is this a setting that maybe can be turned off?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure it behaves this way? Also you should not use single quotes for html attributes, use double quotes "

Comment: Are you sure coldfusion is doing this and not your browser or whatever is interpreting the html? `href='#!year=2016'` is identical to `href='http://example.com:80/snapshots/#!year=2016'` if you're viewing the page `http://example.com:80/snapshots/`

Comment: Sounds like the `resolveURL` property might be what you're looking for. The default value of `no` would prevent it from doing that.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, it was the resolveURL that was set to yes. That was what was causing it

Comment: Isn't `ResolveURL` only in `cfhttp`?

Comment: @henry I'm using cfhttp requests for this because this an embeddable app that is to be embedded on third party sites. Rather than rewrite snapshots, I'm using server-side requests from a coldfusion script so I don't have to rewrite them for every language those sites might be using.

Comment: @KevinB wanna make you answer an actual answer so it can be marked thus? Good detective work, btw.